# How can I recover my php deleted data?

Tags: php, file, xampp, recover

I am using **XAMPP** server and sublime text editor for **php**. I installed new windows 10. My all php work is deleted because it was saved in C-drive. How can I **recover** my **php** deleted data?

Comment: this isn't a programming question.

Comment: *Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour).*

Comment: you should invest in an external backup drive for the future